# Caliburn.Micro : CoRoutine , What is it?

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro

[Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro) is a framework for C# application.

[image]

There is "CoRoutine" ( [document is here](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/coroutines) )

Here is an example code from [here](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/samples/features/Features.CrossPlatform.Shared/ViewModels/CoroutineViewModel.cs).

```
        yield return new VisualStateResult("Loading");
        yield return TaskHelper.Delay(2000).AsResult();
        yield return new VisualStateResult("LoadingComplete");
        yield return new MessageDialogResult("This was executed from a custom IResult, MessageDialogResult.", "IResult Coroutines");
```

I read the document many time, but I do not understand CoRoutine at all.
In my understanding, It is just simple 4 x asynchronous task. sorry I do not understand the benefit of CoRoutine at all.

Please explain someone about it's benefit and example......

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view the CoRoutine is a method that you can start, suspend, resume and stop.

If you suspend the CoRoutine then the state of method is saved and you can resume the method later from the saved state and execute the next line.

Comment: in above Example code, I know How to "start". but How to "suspend" or "resume" ?  if  I want to stop code Before "TaskHelper", How to do it ?                Dose "ResultCompletionEventArgs" help it ??